# How to paginate over multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have three or more models with the same table schema and the same number of records.

```
ford
----
id
model

toyota
----
id
model

chevrolet
----
id
model
```

I want to create a webpage **with pagination** where I display all three tables interleaved by id.  For example:

```
id     model
----   -----
1      Fusion
1      Corolla
1      Camaro
2      Explorer
2      Camry
2      Volt
```

I attempted to do this with the following controller:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @cars = []
    @ford = Ford.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    @toyota = Toyota.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    @chevrolet = Chevrolet.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

    for i in 0..@ford.size-1 do
      @cars << @ford[i]
      @cars << @toyota[i]
      @cars << @chevrolet[i]
    end
  end
end
```

Pagination works up to the last page.  I get an error in the last page because less than 10 records are returned.  The iteration over @cars in the view somehow expects 10 records.  Thus, I get a null reference error.

I do not want to get all of the records from the ford, toyota, and chevrolet tables and then paginate.  I want to request the records in batches, and then simply display them. My method is very likely the wrong way to do this.  Any suggestions?  Perhaps, I can create a view and query that?

Comment: A little confused about why you're using paginate to query the records, but I'll take your word for why you want that. You can set the :per_page separately from what I can tell (on the model)  self.per_page = 10 and then use limits on the query? Ford.limit(10)

Comment: You can use sql 'union'. But this design is just wrong. Why do you have separate tables for different cars?? As a sidenote, 'for' loop is rarely seen in ruby world, use some iterator instead to do it the ruby way.

Comment: @creativereason I am not sure if `paginate` should be used in the way I am using it.  I know that it works when using only one model.  I do not have a Cars model that is why I am building the `@cars` array this way.

Comment: @cthulhu I see why you would want to have a single table for each car but then again I should not have to redesign my database to work nicely with a framework.  There can be cases where one cannot make such a change.

Comment: Terrible database design won't work nicely with any framework. But as I mentioned, you can try to use sql UNION